# Why must the Pesach Korban had to be eaten entirely

Tags: passover, korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, korban-pesach

Why does the Pesach Korban in Lev 22:30 have to be eaten in its entirety and nothing should remain till next morning?

Comment: Which Korbanot don't need to be eaten in their entirety? In fact more generally, which food is allowed to be wasted?

Comment: It's like all korbanos

Comment: I understand its a Korbanot, but what is the rationale behind it, is there a deeper spiritual meaning?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?Also unless the number 18783 means something special to you, you can pick up a more memorable name if you wish. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: [Lev. 22:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.22.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0) is about the Korban Todah - Thanksgiving Offering, not the Korban Pesach. Please [edit] to clarify which of these you're asking about, or both. If you're asking about the Korban Pesach, please replace your Torah reference with one that refers to it.